# Which Adult Ads Service is best / highest paying

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, adult-content

I have a sex education & sexual health website. As evident, I can not place Google Adsense and Adbrite advertisements as they disallow mature content and even remotely anything related to it.

Now, I want to know what are the other options I have for showing up ads. **I do NOT want to place very obscene and nude ads.** But, I would like to have some kind of ads on website to make it sustainable. So, what options do I have ? Which adult advertisement publisher gives highest payouts ?

Answer (score 2):

[E-Consultant's Top 10 Advertising Networks](http://lists.econsultant.com/top-10-advertising-networks.html)  may help. For instance [Kanoodle](http://www.kanoodle.com/) have an extensive sign-up form that suggests negotiation is possible (plus the name matches the subject of your site). Some have a percentage of revenue displayed beside them (but not the average advert value).

You may also wish to review [the big list of ad networks](http://3things.be/wp-content/uploads/ad-networks.txt). For instance a 5 minute flick through [shows that Miva believe](http://www.miva.com/legal_center/advertiser-relevancy-guidelines)

> adult content can be considered objectionable

the "can" bit may provide some leeway.

Good luck, trying to read around this area shows how difficult it is.